# Right way to assign Events to all gameobjects

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

Ten cubes inside in my gameobject hitting each other and now i want to detect OnTriggerEnter. What is the correct way to do this?

I can do it some thing like this (script below) and assign it to each gaemobject. isn't the tedious way to do this?

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c) {
        Debug.Log("hit");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do it. The reason is that you want to check for each box if it is colliding. If you want only one method then you can have only one box.

But you can also do it in few lines so you don't have to add them manually.

```
public class CollisionController:MonoBehaviour{
    private void Awake(){
       foreach(Transform t in transform){
           if(t == this.transform) { continue; }
           t.gameObject.AddComponent<CollisionMethod>();
       }
    }
}
```

And this is the script containing the collision method.

```
public class CollisionMethod:MonoBehaviour{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c) {
        Debug.Log("hit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the collider gameobject has any identifying tag on it and execute any code afterwards. You can lower an enemy's HP for example and destroy it if it would reach 0 and so on.

As far as I know it's perfectly fine to use this. Worked out for me in the past.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c) {
     if(c.gameObject.tag == "Player"){


        /* Whatever you want to do when 
        "Player" enters the collider goes here... */

     }

}
```

PS.: Staying with your ten cubes example you can have a "Cube" tag for them and check for it - then do your code whenever a "Cube" tagged gameobject enters into your collider.